# Plotting Multiple boolean cols in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart

I got a DF with two column that shows if a person have dept in this month and the previous one.

```
Moroso morosoant
1      0
1      1
0      0
```

So I'd like to plot the amount of paid and unpaid for both cols.

I've tried this for ploting the values for just on

```
sn.catplot(kind="bar",x="MOROSO",y="MOROSO",data=pd.DataFrame(df["MOROSO"].value_counts()))
```

[image]

I would like to add the morosoant col next to the moroso column.

Comment: How do you want to value counts from `morosoant` to be displayed? Do you want two more bars, or do you want the bars to be paired with the current bars from `MOROSO`?

Comment: I'd like to add the morosoant col next keeping the color distinction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seaborn's works easiest with a dataframe in ["long form"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data). Pandas' `melt()` can combine the columns.  Using `kind='count'`, seaborn does the counting.  To have names for the `0`s and `1`s in the legend, `.replace()` can change them to strings. Matplotlib's new `bar_label` function labels the bars with their value.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Moroso': np.random.randint(0, 2, 100),
                   'Morosoant': np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)})
df_long = df.melt(value_vars=['Moroso', 'Morosoant'], value_name='Legend').replace({'Legend': {0: 'No', 1: 'Yes'}})
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
g = sns.catplot(kind='count', data=df_long,
                x='variable', hue='Legend', palette='Set1', height=4, aspect=2)
g.set(xlabel='')
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    for bars in ax.containers:
        ax.bar_label(bars)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.07, bottom=0.15)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.catplot with kind='count']

PS: If `df` looks like:

```
   Moroso  Morosoant
0       0          1
1       1          1
2       1          0
3       1          1
4       0          1
```

Then `df_long` (before the replace) will look like:

```
    variable  Legend
0     Moroso       0
1     Moroso       1
2     Moroso       1
3     Moroso       1
4     Moroso       0
5  Morosoant       1
6  Morosoant       1
7  Morosoant       0
8  Morosoant       1
9  Morosoant       1
```

Comment: Thank u so much, that's exactly what I was looking for. I saw melt in other post but I didn't get it, I'll read more about it.